# How to put new line in php file fwrite

Tags: php, fwrite, file-writing

I am writing a file that is `plan.php`. It is a php file that I am writing. I am using `\n` to put the new line in that file but it is giving me save output.

Here is code:

```
$datetime = 'Monthly';
$expiry = '2017-08-07';
$expiryin = str_replace('ly', '',$datetime);
if($expiryin == 'Month' || $expiryin == 'Year') {
    $time = '+ 1'.$expiryin.'s';
} else {
    $time = '+'.$expiryin.'s';
}
   $expiry_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($time, strtotime($expiry)));

$string = createConfigString($expiry_date);

$file = 'plan.php';
$handle = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file);
fwrite($handle, $string);
```

And the function is:

```
function createConfigString($dates){
    global $globalval;

    $str = '<?php \n\n';
    $configarray = array('cust_code','Auto_Renew','admin_name');
    foreach($configarray as $val){
            $str .= '$data["'.$val.'"] = "'.$globalval[$val].'"; \n';
    }
    $str .= '\n';
    return $str;
}
```

But it is giving the output like:

```
<?php   .......something....\n.....\n
```

So my question is how to put the new line in this file.

**Note:** There is no error in code. I have minimized the code to put here.

Comment: Replace `'\n'` to `"\n"`. And read a manual sometimes. You can even use `PHP_EOL` constant.

Comment: @u_mulder After replacing it is giving me error as I am using `$` at the beginning of string.

Comment: You can use `PHP_EOL` as an alternative too instead of `\n`.

Comment: Seriously with such rep you can think of a something like `'";' .  "\n";`

Comment: @u_mulder This is sugarcrm config modification. So I cann't make more changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone already mentioned `'\n'` is just a two symbols string `\n`.

You either need a `"\n"` or php core constant `PHP_EOL`:

```
function createConfigString($dates){
    global $globalval;

    // change here
    $str = '<?php ' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $configarray = array('cust_code','Auto_Renew','admin_name');
    foreach($configarray as $val){
        // change here 
        $str .= '$data["'.$val.'"] = "'.$globalval[$val].'";' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    // change here
    $str .= PHP_EOL;
    return $str;
}
```

More info about interpreting special characters in strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 2):

Replace `'` with `"` ;-)

You can learn more about strings in PHP's manual: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\n` inside a single-quoted string (`$var = '\n';`), it will be just that - the litteral string `\n`, and not a newline. For PHP to interpret that it should in fact be a newline, you need to use doublequotes (`$var = "\n";`).

```
$var = '\n';     // The litteral string \n
$var = "\n";     // Newline
```

- [PHP.net on double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)
- [**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Bdgjg)

Answer (score 0):

`\n` does not work inside single quotes such as `'\n'`. You need to use double quotes `"\n"`. So for your purpose, the change you need to make is:

```
function createConfigString($dates){
  global $globalval;

  $str = '<?php \n\n';
  $configarray = array('cust_code','Auto_Renew','admin_name');
  foreach($configarray as $val){
        $str .= "$data['".$val."'] = '".$globalval[$val]."'; \n"; // change places of double and single quotes
  }
  $str .= "\n"; // change places of double and single quotes
  return $str;
}
```