# Cannot add line break to file

Tags: codeigniter

I am going to make function that writes all activity logs on my webpage. I'm using Codeigniter 3x as the framework. Here is the code.

```
public function writeLog($loc, $user, $activity) {
    $this->load->helper('file');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $files = FCPATH . '/assets/logs/logs-' . date('Y-m-d') . ".log";
    $data = date("H:i:s") . " | User: " . $user . " from IP " . $loc . " do activity " . $activity . "\n";
    write_file($files, $data, "a");
}
```

When I'm about to call the function by writeLog("192.168.1.3", "blackjack", "login"), it should be written like this:

```
15:20:22 | blackjack from IP 192.168.1.3 do activity login
```

But when I call that function again by writeLog("192.168.1.3", "blackjack", "logout"), the result like this:

```
15:20:22 | blackjack from IP 192.168.1.3 do activity login15:20:39 | blackjack from IP 192.168.1.3 do activity logout
```

I have inserted `"\n"` in the end of the `$data`, but new line isn't created.

Please help me

Comment: Are you using a windows computer to read the log files? If so, which program?

Comment: How are you viewing this file? Are you using Notepad on Widows? Are you looking at it in a web browser?

Comment: you can use PHP_EOL

Comment: Try using \r\n instead of \n, that would maybe work.

Comment: I am using notepad in Windows computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put new line in php file fwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942968/how-to-put-new-line-in-php-file-fwrite)

Comment: Notepad will not display `\n` line breaks. Some other editors will though.

Comment: To make the code a bit easier to read, you might want to skip the `.`'s in the double-quoted string concatenation or rather use the `sprintf` method which takes a format and a bunch of arguments. This has nothing to do with the question though... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different Operating systems use different characters for line endings. On unix-like systems the line ending is `\n` (called LF) while windows use `\r\n` (called CRLF). Most windows programs can display `\n` but not all.
Best way to go about is to use the `PHP_EOL` constant and let the server decide what line endings to use.

Extra curiosa: Mac OSX uses LF now days but older mac's used only CR.

Comment: Best way to go about is to use the PHP_EOL constant and let the server decide what line endings to use. - well said